# How should the chain be routed on this deraillier?

Tags: chain

I feel dumb asking this, but how should the chain be routed around the cogs on this deraillier?

I had to split the chain and then put it back on. I didn't pay attention to how it went round. This is not the right way (below) as the chain is extremely slack.

[image]

Comment: Look at the picture in the question below 'Can't find the B-tension screw in rear derailleur' It schow quite nicely how your chain should be routed.

Comment: Thanks, but which one is the front idler wheel? And I don't really get what you mean by 'over'.

Comment: look at literally any picture of any derailleur, they all work the same way.

Answer (score 12):

[image: chain routing]

You almost made it...   Obviously bottom long line should run straight to crankset.  You will feel some spring tension when you route the chain.

Comment: Nice answer @zipzit. Perhaps it would be improved by adding the image at http://i.stack.imgur.com/kiT7N.jpg, used in [this recent question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/38938/8273).

Comment: Please note that somewhere around the middle of the blue line, not visible in the perspective of the picture, there is a metal tab. It is quite easy to ignore it and then get strange rub in the chain (as the chains attempts to grind away the tab). Solution - intentionally pay attention to the tab, route the chain so that it does not rub.

Comment: @Vorac Good point – it's easy to get that wrong.  I've been doing my own bike maintenance for years and I still make that mistake when I'm not paying attention!

Answer (score 0):

The chain that comes in from the bottom right of the photo should pass around the idler gear it currently runs to clockwise (which it is doing), between the two idler gears, around the other idler gear counterclockwise, then to the bottom of the cassette, around the cassette clockwise, and off to the top of the front chain ring.

Comment: so in the picture it's correct on the right cog, but wrong on the left cog?

Comment: I don't see it going around the rightward idler (which will be the top one) at all.  It goes to the idler that is now to the left, which will be bottom, and I don't see it leave.  It seems to stop just as it passes behind the control cable.